# Detection issues of QR-code from photo

Tags: android, barcode

What I am trying to do: Search for QR-code with the camera, at detection of QR code take a picture of it and then scan the picture once more to find the location of the QR-code in the picture. I know that I can get the location of the QR-code from a surfaceholder in a surfaceview but since I need to extract more data from the image depending on the QR-code location I need to get the image and run a detector on it again.

Issue: After detecting and taking a picture of the QR-code the second "scan" does not detect the QR-code in the image.

My code below

```
barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                    .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
                    .build();

cameraSource = new CameraSource
            .Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(1794, 1080)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
            .build();
```

When a QR-code is detected this method runs which takes a picture of the QR-code

```
cameraSource.takePicture(null, new CameraSource.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes) {

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

            detectorOnBitMap();
        }
    });
```

After converting the byte array to a bitmap this following method is called

```
    public void detectorOnBitMap() {

    Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bmp).build();

    colorview.setImageBitmap(frame.getBitmap());

    SparseArray<Barcode> barcodesTRUE = barcodeDetector.detect(frame);

    if (barcodesTRUE.size() != 0) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Found QR-code");


    } else {
        Log.d("Tag", "Did not find QR-code");
    }
}
```

But somehow the detector does not find the QR code in the bitmap. Why? Tried showing the bitmap in an Imageview and the picture looks like it should. Tried saving it to a jpeg/png and then scan it after loading the image which works, but only after compressing the bitmap. Did I do something wrong when converting the byte array to a bitmap?

Thanks in advance!